# Signal with requests module does not work

Tags: django, python-requests

I am trying to make a post request using the requests module in order to save data to a remote url.

But the signal seems not working, nothing happen when a record is saved and I got no log...

Can you tell me what's wrong and how can I get more informations ?

**models.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Record)
def post_record(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        record = instance

        payload = {
            'name': record.name
        }

        r = requests.post('http://.../', data = payload)

        print(r.status_code)

        if r.status_code != 200:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Request to server returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s'
                    % (r.status_code, r.text)
                )
```

Comment: Hard to tell with just that info. Are you sure you've called save() on a Record instance? Are you sure post_record is called? Are you sure kwargs['created'] is truthy? Easy way to know is to add some print statements.

Comment: Hey Daniel, yes the save() method is called. I can simply tell that because the records are saved in the admin. This kwargs seems good too because I am using it with an other signal.

Comment: Add a print statement before the if to know **for sure** if it's running (it probably is but still).

Comment: Hello, indeed, this is what I did ; in order to track every step and I manage to solve my problem